# should i choose SQL over NoSQL?

Tags: sql, database, nosql, relational

Well, basically I'm working on a web application that may get quite bigger over the time. 
For now I just need basic user information, so i was thinking that a SQL db should be enough, but as in the future it may need to save more info that I did not have in mind (I'm not talking about a forum, but maybe info like messages or a user board), I thought having a NoSQL db would be better.

Comment: It's totally depends on your application needs. In some projects NoSQL suits good, and in some projects using traditional RDBMS is much better choise.

Comment: I also sense from your question that you assume NoSQL being better at larger amounts of data. That is not true. The choice is based on the use, just like a hammer and a screwdriver. It’s not about hammer or a sledgehammer. In any case you haven’t given any specifics so this cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be thinking about this in terms of either/or - adopt the notion of Polyglot Persistence - multiple data stores for different purposes.

- Need to be able to stored highly structured data with lots of joins or relationships between objects? Use a Relational database.
- Need to have flexible data structure, with dynamic metadata that cannot be easily foreseen? consider a Document Oriented database
- Need to identify complex relationships between objects and trace nodal relationships looking for patterns that are hard to ascertain across multiple links? use a a Graph database
- Need to have lightning fast real-time responsive search and interactive look up to iteratively narrow down choices? use a Key Value pair data store.

I highly recommend the book *No SQL Distilled* by Martin Fowler and Pramod Sadalage to explain this topic well. It is not very big, which helps.